# Scheduled backup errors

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, jobs

I am trying to do the following. I have about 50 DBs and a network NAS that acts as backup machine. I have made an sql script(lets say backup.sql) with 50 lines each of these say "BACKUP DATABASE ABC TO DISK='Y:\ABC.bak'". Also, I have a .bat file with a single command "sqlcmd -i backup.sql -o logs.txt". When I execute it I take a message in the log that say:

> HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections..
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Login timeout expired.

I have to mention that I want to make the backup from sql server 2008. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a batch file to backup the databases?  Why not put the code in a SQL Agent job and have that kick off the backup?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is using the Express edition?  Even so, I'd probably go about that a different way as well.

Comment: As Surfer513 say, I have SQL express version. :(

Comment: That explains why no SQL Agent.  Are you running this backup job on the SQL Server itself or another machine?

Comment: On the SQL server itself.

Comment: Is it a named instance like SQLEXPRESS or is it the default instance?

Comment: Where I can find the instance name? :S

Comment: When you connect in SQL Server Management studio it's the part to the right of the "\".  Or find the service in the services app in Admin tools.  It'll be the part in parns "(SQLEXPRESS)" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, sqlcmd connects to local machine, using integrated authentication.
You need to specify options for server and login to your sqlcmd call.
So you'd need something like:

> sqlcmd -i backup.sql -o logs.txt -S ComputerA

Or change the backup.sql script to use sqlcmd mode and use :connect command to change the server.

See details on MSDN:

- [sqlcmd utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)
- [How to: Connect to the Database Engine Using sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188247.aspx)

Comment: I added the switch -S 127.0.0.1 but nothing different happened :(